# Did this Elephants ear get sunburn?

Tags: plant-care

I bought this plant and put it next to a south facing window on a sunny day. 2 days later I noticed the leaf had this big yellow/brown patch on it. Is this characteristic of being sunburnt or something else?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello Tom,  Can you take a picture of the whole plant?  Are any of the other leaves damaged?  Where do you live that a South facing window in winter might too sunny? Was the leaf touching the window?  Is there a draft or vent by the window?

Comment: A pic showing the pot as well would be helpful - how long have you had the plant?

Comment: The plant was almost brand new when the first photo was taken - I bought it 2 days previously. I'm in london UK. The leaf was next to the window, but not touching it. There is a vent but it's a few metres away. I've added some more pictures showing the whole plant - some leaves are healthier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a much larger pot, but your assumption about sunburn is correct - grown indoors, these plants will like medium to bright daylight, but not direct sun.

It does look as if you're going to have to move it up to a larger pot asap.. these plants get very large indeed so it needs a pot that's probably two to three times bigger than the one it is currently in, with drainage holes. Keep the soil evenly damp, but not waterlogged - empty out any outer tray or pot 30 minutes after watering. Bear in mind it will take up a fair bit of space in the room too, so find a spot for it where it gets good daylight, away from heat sources, and has sufficient room around the topgrowth for it to spread itself out as it grows. More info here https://www.hallmarkchannel.com/home-and-family/how-to/how-to-care-for-indoor-elephant-ear-plants

Comment: Should I cut off any unhealthy leaves that have brown patches and are drooping or leave them to die on the plant?

Comment: You can cut off the worst ones at the base, but take care not to damage other parts of the plant as you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Both ! The almost silver parts of the leaf is where "bleaching" has occurred caused by UV radiation.

The brown parts are the something else

And the fact that its drooping is also a sign that there is something else